# Where is the subquery in this statement?

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery

The following code is returning **ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row**, but I cannot determine why that's happening.  What part of this statement is being treated as a subquery?

```
SELECT
    ada.schoolid,
    s.dcid,
    s.lastfirst,
    s.grade_level,
    s.home_room,
    s.home_phone,
    SUM(ada.membershipvalue) - SUM(ada.attendancevalue) absences,
    SUM(ada.membershipvalue) membership,
    ROUND( ( SUM( ada.membershipvalue ) - SUM(ada.attendancevalue) ) / SUM( ada.membershipvalue ) * 100, 2) absenceRate
FROM
    students s
    JOIN schools schl ON schl.school_number = s.schoolid
    JOIN ps_adaadm_defaults_all ada ON ada.studentid = s.id and ada.schoolid in (87)
WHERE
    s.pl_language = '31516argul'
    AND to_date(ada.calendardate) >= to_date('9/01/2007', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    AND to_date(ada.calendardate) <= to_date('6/20/2016','mm/dd/yyyy' )
    AND ada.membershipvalue > 0
GROUP BY 
    ada.schoolid, 
    s.dcid, 
    s.lastfirst, 
    s.grade_level, 
    s.home_room, 
    s.home_phone
ORDER BY
    s.lastfirst ASC
```

Comment: are those all tables?, or are you using some views?. Is that the whole code?

Comment: @Lamak ps_adaadm_defaults_all is a view.  This is the whole code.

Comment: and can you do `SELECT * FROM ps_adaadm_defaults_all `?

Comment: Is this the exact code that you're running and getting the error? Is the 87 always hardcoded like that?

Comment: @Lamak Yes, `SELECT * FROM ps_adaadm_defaults_all` works

Comment: @Tom There is always a value hard-coded in that location, it is not always 87.  That value represents different schools.

Comment: @BrianBrock . . . I do not believe that the code in the question could generate this error.  It has no subqueries.

Comment: Can you post the definition of that view too. Although pretty unlikely, I've seen cases where something weird inside the view causes unexpected errors with the way they are joined.

Comment: The execution plan might reveal something odd happening too. It might need to be traced to see what's really happening though.

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to accomplish here? may be an example of what you are trying to achieve and what you are getting using this query?

Comment: I can tell you that... try putting`and ada.schoolid in (87)` under where clause

Answer (score 0):

You have two options.  Either whatever code you use that generates the `87` is causing the problem (unlikely given your explanation in the comments), or `ps_adaadm_defaults_all` is causing the problem.  Post the view definition and we can figure out how you can fix it, but what's happening is your db is picking an execution plan that breaks that view by joining tables in a different order.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't post and sample output data...we are blind to your data.

I believe `and ada.schoolid in (87)` should not be in join statement. 
Try moving it under where clause

```
where ada.schoolid in (87)
    AND s.pl_language = '31516argul'
    AND to_date(ada.calendardate) >= to_date('9/01/2007', 'mm/dd/yyyy')
    AND to_date(ada.calendardate) <= to_date('6/20/2016','mm/dd/yyyy' )
    AND ada.membershipvalue > 0
```

Comment: which table has multiple rows of data for unique id?

Comment: Oracle doesn't generally care for inner joins and would come up with the same plan and access/filter predicates; it internally rewrites in the old syntax anyway. I suppose if the view is causing the problem somehow then it could have some effect; I doubt it but would be interesting to check.

Comment: I believe one of the table has multiple rows of data is distinct `    ada.schoolid` ; I'd like to know more about the table data.

Answer (score 0):

You are joining students to schools (by schoolid), but not joining schools to ps_adaadm_defaults_all? Yet you are limiting ps_adaadm_defaults_all to schoolid in (87). That seems inconsistent -- you're getting all student records for all schoolids from the 1st join, then ps_adaadm_defaults_all values (for schoolid=87) are being used for ALL schoolids in schools.

Comment: The `ada.studentid = s.id` will still restrict to a single school, indirectly. Or at least to all students who are associated with that school; I guess a student might be listed against more than one school. This doesn't address the error being seen, though that could feed in to how Oracle is rewriting the query internally to handle the (apparently very complicated apparently) view. Perhaps it only affects schools which have students who are also at other schools.